# Cron expression for a particular date

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want a `cron` expression that run at 9:25 am, 13:25 pm, 14:55 pm everyday. 
I have tried many ways, but failed.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You could do this with multiple cron jobs by specifying the exact time for each one with identical commands.

Comment: I can do with one date.But i have no idea for multiple date

Comment: Just create a cron job that runs every day at 9:25am, then another one that runs every day for 13:25pm...

Comment: looking at the quartz cron configuration i don't think you can do them all in one cron. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: Okay,i got it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating separate cron job lines for each specific time.

In `crontab` this would look like:

```
25 9 * * * your_command >/dev/null 2>&1
25 13 * * * your_command >/dev/null 2>&1
55 14 * * * your_command >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve by creating one cron job?

Comment: To be honest I don't think it is, I think you'll need to use separate cron jobs as you can't specify multiple lines in a cronjob line.

Comment: Thanks for Jamesking56